# Configuring where jest searches for snapshots

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I start to use jest to write tests for a old product. There somewhere deep in the directories are .snap files which have nothing to do with jest. But my jest test runs are failing, because jest finds these files:

```
jest -- __tests__

 PASS  __tests__/userPreferences.test.js
 PASS  __tests__/hierachyCollapse.test.js

Snapshot Summary

› 35 obsolete snapshot files found, run with `npm test -- -u` to remove them..

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.556s
Ran all test suites matching /__tests__/i.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

How can I tell jest to look for snapshots in **tests**/**snapshots** as it is meant to be?

I've found [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1650) but that does not really seem to fit my problem.